# Wireless does not activate when the computer starts up. It works after the first hibernation

Tags: wireless, asus

I have a Asus f550c laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. When it starts up, the wireless device is off, and the key combination <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to turn it on does not work.

To activate the wireless device, the work around I have been using is to hibernate the laptop and to recover it from hibernation. After the laptop comes out of hibernation for some magical reason the wireless card works.

Does anyone have a solution to avoid having to use this hibernation workaround, so that the wireless card works on startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please copy and paste this command:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Reboot and wifi should work.

Here is the link with full details courtesy of varun and chili555.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird problem like this but its most likely a completely separate issue but the solution might be the same.

Check to see if

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
```

works where wlan0 is your wireless card name. If you don't know the name of your card, use

```
ipconfig
```

or

```
ip -a
```

to find it out.

Then try

```
sudo ifup wlan0
```

If this works, add it into your /etc/rc.local which is the script that runs on start up. It's a bit hacky but I hope it works!

If it doesn't. Then I suspect it might be a power management problem.